# How do I post comments without authorization via web browser?

Tags: php, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I want to post a comment via Youtube API.

Currently my working code does that, yet I need to authorize via web browser and after some repetition it says invalid credentials and the comments are not being posted any more.

What is the reason for the invalid credentials message and how do I post comments without authorization via web browser, i.e. by having my server run a php-script via `cron` every two days?

Comment: You should share your current code.

Comment: @BurakTokak Why?

Comment: Right at this state of your question it seems like you are trying to make people write the code you need for you. If you supply some of your progress, stackoverflow community can navigate you and give you tips about how you can achive what you are trying to do.

Comment: @BurakTokak While you are wrong about your assumption, I find it to be more work to understand other people's code than supplying my own.

Comment: Just a hunch, but I think you are Authorising each time. Should only need to once for app or site. Then use your refresh token in the background to keep your connection. Info is in the v3 api documentation for this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be authorize to YouTube to perform this method. If you want to post a comment, then the [`CommentThreads: insert`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/commentThreads/insert) can help you to create a new top-level comment.

Here is the sample request on how to do that. Just replace the videoId to the videoId that you want to comment.

https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.commentThreads.insert?part=snippet&_h=24&resource=%257B%250A++%2522snippet%2522%253A+%250A++%257B%250A++++%2522topLevelComment%2522%253A+%250A++++%257B%250A++++++%2522snippet%2522%253A+%250A++++++%257B%250A++++++++%2522textOriginal%2522%253A+%2522your+comment+here%2522%252C%250A++++++++%2522videoId%2522%253A+%2522kmXXXLBL3Nk%2522%250A++++++%257D%250A++++%257D%250A++%257D%250A%257D&

You can check here the [sample code](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/commentThreads/insert#examples) on how to do this with PHP code.

Note that you need to be authorize to perform this.

For the invalid credentials that you got, check the PHP sample code [here](https://www.hitchhq.com/youtube/activities/commentthreads-insert-youtube-data-api-google-developers-575bf734bfdd411100ce5fb6) on how to solve that kind of error.

Hope this information helps you.